# How to delete the pattern line and lines after it until whitespace using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Given something like this:

pattern
line1
line2

line3
line4

I want to delete the pattern and everything under it until the blank line, is there a way to do that with sed or another bash editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/pattern/,/^$/d' File
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
awk '/pattern/ {f=1} !f; !NF {f=0}' file
line3
line4
```

It will also work if blank line does contain spaces. `^$` will not.

Comment: Don't think you need the f after !NF `awk '/pattern/{f=1}!x;!NF{f=0}'`

Comment: @Jidder You are correct, since `f` only will be set if `pattern` is found.  Corrected

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax.

```
Shell> cat /tmp/list
line1
line2

line3
line4
Shell> cat /tmp/list  |sed -e '/line1/,/^$/ d'
line3
line4
```

Comment: If this is the answer you are expecting then accept the answer.

Comment: 1. You do not need to use `cat` with program like `sed`.  2. `-e` is not needed, since you have only one action. 3. OP should always accept answer if he can, but with reutation 1 he can not. And its always good to wait some hour before acceping, since a better answer may show up. 4. This is wrong answer, since it should be `/pattern/,/^$/d` and not `line1`

Comment: A correction to `4.`.  I do see you have different input than `OP` so solution is ok.